# How to forced my PackingSlipId by code in CustPackingSlipJour?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, number-sequence

I'm creating `SalesTable` and `SalesLine`, and after I call this function,

```
SalesFormLetter_PackingSlip = SalesFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::PackingSlip);
SalesFormLetter_PackingSlip.parmId(MYTABLE.MYPackingSlipId);                 
SalesFormLetter_PackingSlip.update(SalesTable,M_MYTABLE.DocumentDate,SalesUpdate::All);
```

But when creating the `CustPackingSlipJour` it set the sales order status to Delivered, but the field `CustPackingSlipJour.PackingSlipId` is set by a NumberSequence.

I set Manual the Number Sequence, but nothing work.
Is it possible to Pick order and set the `PackingSlipId` with my value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packing slip id of the sales order is set by AX using a number sequence.
You will need a customization, if you want change that.

Comment: @ JanB.Kjeldsen, thanks for answer, but if I set in `SalesFormLetter_PackingSlip.parmId(MYTABLE.MYPackingSlipId);`it's not possible to set the value on CustPackingSlipJour.PackingSlipId ?

Comment: No, `parmId` is not used for that.

Comment: Thanks @Jan B. Kjeldsen.